# How to set token value in headers when uploading a file angular

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, http-headers

I am uploading a file using angular and node.js API.
I am following [this](http://angularcode.com/simple-file-upload-example-using-angularjs/) link to upload a file.
 In this tutorial we need to set header `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}`

On other hand I need to set headers value for `authentication token` . For that I am setting default headers value like as  `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = $cookieStore.get('token');`

Now when I uploading a file then a error is shwoing i.e

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Now please let me know how can I resolve this..
Or any solution to achieve this.
Thanks

Below is the Service and Controller for file upload

```
 app.service('fileUpload', ['$http','$cookieStore', function ($http, $cookieStore) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
                var token = $cookieStore.get('token') ; 
               var fd = new FormData();
               fd.append('file', file);

               $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {transformRequest: angular.identity,headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} }) 
               .success(function(res){
               })
               .error(function(){
               });
            }
         }]);


app.controller('csvCtrl', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.importcsv=function(){
            var file=$scope.myFile;
            var uploadUrl="/api/parsecsv";
            fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        }
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the function that is calling the $http that uploads the file?

Comment: yes , I updated question with file upload service and controller

Answer (score 0):

This should get you to the point of being able to apply the header:

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', '$cookieStore', function ($http, $cookieStore) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
        var token = $cookieStore.get('token');
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, 
            {
                transformRequest: angular.identity, 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined,
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            })
            .success(function (res) {
            })
            .error(function () {
            });
    }
}]);
```

Once you get that working, you can set the default headers with an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Comment: You will need to remove the line that does `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = $cookieStore.get('token');`

Comment: Which headers are getting set before you make the request? Check in the network panel in dev tools

Comment: First `Authorization` and then `Content-Type`

Comment: What I mean is, are they actually getting attached to the request? Check the network tab and see what headers are attached to the request.

Comment: Yes... headers are attaching into requests.

Comment: `Accept, Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Authorization,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Cookie,Host,Origin,Referer,User-Agent` These all are in `request headers`

Comment: And the error you get is in the response? Or that is in the dev console?

Comment: No...that is not in response .